# Question about random samplings and estimations.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

100  students  were  selected  to  participate  in  a  survey  by  the  school  in  May  2013.  The  next  month,  another  100 students  were  randomly  selected  to  participate  in  the  same  survey,  out  of  which  2  had  already  participate  in the  survey  the  previous  month.  If  the  number  of  students  did  not  change  from  May  to  June  then  what  is  the approximate number of students in the school?

Came across this question. Is the question weird or am I just dumb? Can anyone suggest a way to solve this or an approach on how it can be solved. Thank you.

Comment: If there are $n$ students then by means of linearity of expectation it can be calculated that the expectation of the number of students that are selected twice equals $n\frac{100^2}{n^2}$. If this equals $2$ then $n=5000$. That is the idea behind it.

Comment: 100²/n² is the probability of a person getting selected twice. This I understand but linearity of expectation means that sum of expected value of the sum of random variables is equal to the sum of their individual expected values right? I don't understand how this comes into play here. Can you please elaborate. Thank you!

Comment: Yes @drhab please elaborate

Comment: @P.J. I have turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ students.

Number them with $i=1,2,\dots,n$ and let $S_i$ take value $1$ if student $i$ is selected twice, and value $0$ otherwise.

Note that: $$\mathbb ES_i=P(S_i=1)=\left(\frac{100}{n}\right)^2$$for every $i$.

If we set:$$S:=\sum_{i=1}^nS_i$$then $S$ is exactly the number of students that are chosen twice.

Taking its expectation by applying linearity of expectation we find:$$\mathbb ES=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^n S_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb ES_i=n\cdot\left(\frac{100}{n}\right)^2=\frac{10000}{n}$$

The fact that exactly $2$ students were chosen twice makes it reasonable to go for $\mathbb ES=2$ which leads to $n=5000$.

Comment: Wonderful! When you do it, it looks so simple..